# async.js browser example incomplete

Tags: javascript, browser, async.js

[https://github.com/caolan/async][1]

Has exactly 1 "In the Browser" example which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="async.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    async.map(data, asyncProcess, function(err, results){
        alert(results);
    });
</script>
```

but this is incomplete since "data" and "asyncProcess" are undefined.
Can someone please supply simple values for these variables so
that I can see a working example?
Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data should be an array of items.

```
[
  {log: "item1"},
  {log: "item2"}
]
```

and asyncProcess should be a function with item and a callback function as arguments:

```
function asyncProcess(item, callback){
  console.log(item.log);
  callback(null, item.log+" Done");
}
```

it's also well documented in [async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#map)

Comment: Thanks Jacob. If the async documentation on the page you point to was "well documented" I wouldn't have needed to ask this question in the first place. That example is woefully incomplete, and includes a reference to fs.stat which is not defined in browsers (where async.js is designed to run). Furthermore in that doc for async.map, "callback" is used to refer to two different functions. Your example made all the difference. Thanks!